# jQuery if else statement not resetting original checkbox states

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, checkbox

Difficult wording the question sorry guys!

Check out this fiddle to see what I am trying to achieve, http://jsfiddle.net/SzQwh/
But basically when a user checks the checkboxes he needs to equal them to 45 and the other checkboxes then become disabled.

Issue I am having is if you select one 30 credit checkbox and one 15 credit checkbox and then de select the 15 credit checkbox then rest of the checkboxes still remain disabled.

All other instances work perfectly if you play around with the fiddle.

Sorry if this is really obvious but I just cant get my head around what is going wrong

```
var points = 30;
var maxPoints = 45; 
var sum = 0;

    $(':checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });
        $('#total_credits').html(sum);  

        if (sum >= maxPoints) {
            $(':checkbox').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
        } else if (sum >= points) {
            $('.group2 :checkbox').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $(':checkbox:disabled').attr('disabled', false);
        }        
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to change `.attr('disabled', false)` to `.removeAttr('disabled')`?

Comment: Still the same issue with that

Comment: Check my second answer :) this time I like it and it can't do more efficiently in my opinion :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best implementation (only 2 lines logic): http://jsfiddle.net/SzQwh/11/

Moreover you should use prop instead of attr if jQuery version >=1.6!

```
$(':checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', sum >= maxPoints);
$('.group2 :checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', sum >= points);
```

Full code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var points = 30;
    var maxPoints = 45; 
    var sum = 0;

    $(':checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });
        $('#total_credits').html(sum);
        $(':checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', sum >= maxPoints);
        $('.group2 :checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', sum >= points);  
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your help Alberto!

Answer (score 1):

[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sna2stha/SzQwh/2/)
change this part.
ie. remove = from the expression.

```
else if (sum > points)
```

Comment: It's doesn't work. If you check 2x `15` you can check one `30` (then the sum is = 60)

Comment: Yeah thats close but as Nathan mentions I can now select 2 x 30 credits - thanks though

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/SzQwh/5/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var points = 30;
    var maxPoints = 45; 
    var sum = 0;

    $(':checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });
        $('#total_credits').html(sum);  


        if (sum >= points) {
            $('.group2 :checkbox').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
            if (sum >= maxPoints) {
                $(':checkbox').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);

            }  
        else
         {
            $('.group1 :checkbox').attr('disabled', false);
        }        
        } else
         {
            $(':checkbox').attr('disabled', false);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You sir are a star, never thought about separating out the if and else statements that way, works a treat! Thank you very much

Comment: I did quickly and I don't like it very much.. but it works :) hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the logic as shown below:

```
if (sum >= maxPoints) {
        $(':checkbox').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
    } else if (sum == points) {
        $('.group2 :checkbox').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.group1 :checkbox').not(':checked').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(':checkbox:disabled').attr('disabled', false);
    }
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SzQwh/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });
        $('#total_credits').html(sum);  


        if (sum >= maxPoints) {
            $(':checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        } else if (sum >= points) {
            $('.group2 :checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled',    
                                                          true)
            sum <= points
              &&  $('.group1 :checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled',    
                                                               false)
        } else {
            $(':checkbox:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
        }
```

setting **checked/disabled** state of **checkboxes** should be done using `prop()` instead of `attr()`